# Spring security config to require authentication for route does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have spring config, where i am saving spring session in redis.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/register/**", "/api/v1/auth/login" , "/api/v1/profile/**").permitAll();
                auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/profile").authenticated();
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(IF_REQUIRED) //
                    .sessionFixation(SessionManagementConfigurer.SessionFixationConfigurer::newSession) //
                    .maximumSessions(1) //
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            )
            //.exceptionHandling((ex) -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(this.authEntryPoint))
            .logout(out -> out
                    .logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true) // Invalidate all sessions after logout
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .addLogoutHandler(new CustomLogoutHandler(this.redisIndexedSessionRepository))
                    .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
                    )
            )
            .build();
}
```

I want `"/api/v1/auth/profile/**"` route to be accessible for anyone, without authentication, however i want `"/api/v1/auth/profile"` to be accessible only for authenticated users.

Using this config, however i am able to still access /api/v1/auth/profile` authenticated, what i have noticed, that if i use

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
authentication.getPrincipal();
```

The `authentication.isAuthenticated()` results in true and `authentication.getPrincipal()` returns "anonymousUser" , could that be the reason why it passes to the route even tho authentication is required?

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you try to change the order? `auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/profile").authenticated();` before the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal configuration works for me and should work for you as well.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests( (requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/profile/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);
    return http.build();
}
```

To access `/profile` itself I need to be authenticated. To access `/profile/nested` I don't.

If I swap the order to

```java
.requestMatchers("/profile/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
```

then even the `/profile` endpoint is accessible by everyone. So the order matters.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why "/api/v1/auth/profile" is accessible even without authentication is because Spring Security treats it as a wildcard path that includes "/api/v1/auth/profile/**", thus permitting access to any sub-paths under "/api/v1/auth/profile".

To resolve this issue, you can rearrange your "authorizeHttpRequests" configuration to explicitly permit access to "/api/v1/auth/profile" only for authenticated users, and allow "/api/v1/auth/profile/**" for anyone. Here's how you can modify your configuration:

```
    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
    auth.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/register/**", "/api/v1/auth/login", "/api/v1/auth/profile/**").permitAll();
    auth.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll(); // Allow static resources without authentication
    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
})
```

With this change, "/api/v1/auth/profile/**" will remain accessible to anyone, while "/api/v1/auth/profile" will only be accessible to authenticated users.

Regarding your observation about the "Authentication" object having "isAuthenticated()" as "true" and the "principal" being "anonymousUser", this is the default behavior when a request is not authenticated. Spring Security automatically creates an anonymous authentication token to represent unauthenticated users. So even though "isAuthenticated()" returns "true", it doesn't necessarily mean that the user is authenticated in the context of your application's authentication mechanism.

Comment: i am doing exactly what you wrote

Comment: I think that the description is correct. Code snippet is wrong though.